# Route URL Pattern for a method signature that takes an optional list of Strings

Tags: scala, url, get, playframework-2.0

In my Play 2 controller (Scala) I've a method that looks like the following.

```
start(id:String, keywords:Option[List[String]])
```

Basically I want to get pass a list of string as `keywords` where it's  *optional*.

The following doesn't work and gives me a compile error.

```
GET        /start         start(id:String,options:Option[List[String]])
```

The error makes sense because even if this route compiled I'm not sure how I would pass a list of Strings in my GET URL.

I'm looking for suggestions to resolve this.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by wanting a "list of strings" as GET parameters? For example, having http://server/path/program?query_string what would you query string look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're just using keywords, how about comma-separated values in the query string?

```
GET     /start/:id                    controllers.Sample.start(id: String, options: Option[String])

/start/1233?options=key,word,test
```

Then in your controller convert to `Option[List[String]]`:

```
def start(id: String, options: Option[String]) = Action {
    val opts: Option[List[String]] = options.map(_.split(',').filter(_.nonEmpty))

    ...
}
```